# Pulumi Azure: Get Service Principal ObjectId

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, pulumi

I'm running pulumi inside an azure devops pipeline. I need to find the the pipeline Service Principal ObjectId

```
var clientConfig = Output.Create(Pulumi.Azure.Core.Invokes.GetClientConfig());
var clientId = clientConfig.Apply(c => c.ObjectId);
```

This gives me the application ObjectId as an Output, now from here how can I find my Service Principal ObjectId.

I can't do that because clientId is `Output<string>` and ObjectId is expecting `string`

```
var adApp = Output.Create(Pulumi.AzureAD.Invokes.GetApplication(new GetApplicationArgs { ObjectId = clientId}));
var adSp = Output.Create(Pulumi.AzureAD.Invokes.GetServicePrincipal(new GetServicePrincipalArgs { ApplicationId = adApp.App(a => a.ApplicationId)});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Apply` method here:

```csharp
var adApp = clientId.Apply(id => 
    Pulumi.AzureAD.Invokes.GetApplication(
        new GetApplicationArgs { ObjectId = id }));

var adSp = adApp.ApplicationId.Apply(appid =>
    Pulumi.AzureAD.Invokes.GetServicePrincipal(
        new GetServicePrincipalArgs { ApplicationId = appid }));
```